# How to validate "<input type="file">" when same file is chosen many times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I have an input control which allows to choose an .xlsx file

```
<input name="Excelfile" type="file" accept=".xlsx" onchange="fileChange($event)">
```

Whenever a file is chosen `fileChange()` function gets called in which it reads number of worksheets in it and  lists it.

Consider I have a SPA(Single Page Application) which lists the worksheet names when an excel workbook is chosen. Now I choose a file "Sample.xlsx" which has 4 sheets in it, SPA lists all 4 worksheets but when I add another sheet to the workbook while the SPA is still running and choose the same file "Sample.xlsx" it does not list all 5 worksheets in it. But when I restart the SPA it lists all 5 worksheets.

How do I make the changes in workbook reflect without restarting the SPA?

Comment: You haven't said whether you save the workbook before trying to reload, do you?

Comment: Yes ,I save the workbook.

Comment: I thought so, but just in case… ;-) Maybe you can reset the input after the file is loaded so that the next time you select the same file it's seen as a change?

Answer (score 0):

Here what i tried to implement is, make a `files` array, `onchange` event is triggered, it will get the file name and match with the `files` array, if it is not in the array then push file name to the array.

```js
var files = [];
function fileChange(event){
  var fileName = event.target.files[0].name
  if(files.indexOf(fileName) != -1){
    alert('file in list')
    event.target.value = '';
  }else{
    files.push(fileName)
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="Excelfile" type="file" accepts=".xlsx" onchange="fileChange()">
```

Comment: I just need to validate the content of the file even  if it is already present

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to compare size of file, so you should use array of object instead of array of string in the solution of @Akhil. As different files my have same name and extensions.

Comment: thats an improvement,